# hybris CMS Cockpit: preview doesn't work

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I've just set up a new and clean hybris instance, created a b2c accelerator storefront using `ant modulegen` and the receipe `b2c_acc` - and of course I initialized my system after those steps. Everything works fine, but the CMS Cockpit preview.

Every time I try to open the preview of a page within the CMS Cockpit, I receive a HTTP 500 error which is being caused by a NullPointerException within this method of the `DefaultUrlEncoderService` class:

```
@Override
public Collection<String> getEncodingAttributesForSite()
{

    return getCmsSiteService().getCurrentSite().getUrlEncodingAttributes();
}
```

The reason is that `getCurrentSite()` does not return any website, though the page I try to open (e.g. the Homepage) has been assigned to the "apparel-de" website.

Does anybody have a clue what might be the issue?
Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the location protocol from http to https:

https://localhost:9002/cmscockpit/index.zul

Comment: Doing that doesn't show a preview at all (preview content is completely blank) :-(